# how to get the sum value

Tags: java

Please help me solve my problem. How  do I get the sum value?

```
public class Exe {
    int sum;
    public int sumAB(int a,int b) {
        sum=a+b;
        return sum;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Exe e= new Exe();
        e.sumAB(2,3);
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into the `toString()` method and invoking methods and method return types.

Comment: You might want to refer the Java tutorial first.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Since you're new, you should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com).  I also suggest reading some [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the `toString` method has nothing to do here =\

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza _its grtting Exe obj_. From `System.out.println(e);`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis *my problem how to get the sum value* for this you need to recover the `sum` from the `sumAB` method instead of having a `toString` method. Of course, using `toString` is a possible solution but not the most accurate IMO.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza What I understood from his question is that he was getting _Exe obj_ printed, but wanted the sum. I think he did not understand that `System.out.println(e);` called `toString()` on the `Exe` instance, instead expecting the sum the be printed.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes, and probably we have to explain the difference of using `System.out.println(e)` as well.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Wouldn't hurt :). I'll +1 you if you add it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis answer updated with a more in-depth analysis of the difference between using a variable and the `toString` method.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza +1 That's why that was taking kind of long. You're very thorough. Hope that helps OP.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a variable to hold the result of the value returned by the method. The code has comments providing the proper explanation. Also, note that I'm using `sumVar` variable to show that **it is not the same variable** that is in `Exe` class, although **it will have the same value**.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Exe e= new Exe();
        //declaring variable sumVar
        int sumVar;
        //assigning the value returned of e.sumAB into the sumVar variable
        sumVar = e.sumAB(2,3);
        //printing the value of sumVar
        System.out.println(sumVar);
    }
}
```

Note that in this code I'm printing the result of the `sumVar` variable that has the same value of `sum` field in the `Exe` class. Another solution can be done by overridding the `toString` method in the `Exe` class:

```
public class Exe {
    int sum;
    public int sumAB(int a,int b) {
        sum=a+b;
        return sum;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(sum);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Exe e= new Exe();
        e.sumAB(2,3);
        //this method will automatically call e.toString for you
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Note that the `toString` method is more for informative purposes than a single field property value processing. What? I mean that the `toString` method is most used to show the current state of the object instead of be used to return the value of a field. Let's see this in an example:

```
public class Exe {
    int sum;
    public int sumAB(int a,int b) {
        sum=a+b;
        return sum;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(sum);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Exe e= new Exe();
        int sumVar;
        sumVar = e.sumAB(2,3);
        //print the value of sum
        System.out.println(sumVar);
        //print the value of sum using e.toString()
        System.out.println(e);
        //now, printing the result of adding 1 to sum
        System.out.println(1 + sumVar);
        //since you're adding a number you have to explicitly use toString() method
        System.out.println(1 + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Result:

```
5
5
6
15
```

In the last code sample, we will see that it printed `5` as the value of `sumVar` and `5` as the value of `e.toString()`. Then, we need to print `1 + sum` and using both approaches we see that it prints `1 + sumVar` = `6` and `1 + e.toString()` = `15`. Why? Because when adding anything to a `String` it will concatenate it, and `15` is the result of concatenate `1` with `5`.

In short: it would be better to use a variable to hold the result of the values returned by a method.

Comment: Use a different identifier.  Don't want him to think that you're talking about the same `sum` as in `Exe`.

Comment: @SteveP. you mean using a different name for `sum`?

Comment: Yeah.  I find that beginners tend to get confused with the scope of variables/think that identifiers have to be the same in certain circumstances.

Comment: @SteveP. answer updated and added the proper explanation to it.

Comment: `+1` @Luiggi Mendoza, I saw.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, an alternate (if somewhat odd) approach which seems to match the OP's original train of thought.  Overriding `toString` in `Exe` will make the test code perform as expected.

```
public class Exe {
    int sum;
    public int sumAB(int a,int b) {
        sum=a+b;
        return sum;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(sum);
    }
}
```

**Explanation:** When you pass an object to a print method, the print method converts that object to a `String` by calling the object's `toString` method.  If your object does not explicitly implement `toString` (or inherit from a class which does), this will result in `Object#toString` being called.  This is rarely particularly useful as it simply prints out the object's class and hash code.  By explicitly defining a `toString` method you can get the behaviour that the OP seems to expect.

As I stated at the beginning of my answer, this approach is somewhat whimsical. For a more reasonable approach, see the other answers.

Comment: See the explanation section.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Exe e= new Exe();
    int sum = e.sumAB(2,3);
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Or print the value directly without assigning to a variable

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    Exe e= new Exe();
    System.out.println(e.sumAB(2,3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access fields of the instance from outside, unless they are private.

```
public class Exe {
   int sum;
   (...)

System.out.println(e.sum);
```